# why is the faces on my model darker than the others?

Tags: modeling

[image]

around the eyes it just goes dark and i do not know how to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a very unclean topology, you might have to redo some of the parts. Until then go into edit mode, select all vertices and press SHIFT N.
That evens the normals, so none of them point in the wrong direction. If that doesn't work, you'll have to even out those regions yourself either in Edit Mode, or by using the sculpt smooth brush.

Comment: thanks this really did help